# java string concat strange behavior

Tags: java, string, string-concatenation

I am getting strange string **concat** behavior, please help me understand this behavior .

```
String s3 = "ABC";
String s5 = new String(s3);

System.out.println("s5 == s3 "+ s5 == s3); // output: false
System.out.println("s5 == s3 "+ (s5 == s3)); // output: s5 == s3 false
```

Should first print **s5 == s3 false** instead of **false** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a modified version of your first expression, which prints `false`:

```
System.out.println(("s5 == s3 " + s5) == s3); // "s5 == s3 ABC" == "ABC"
```

`==` has lower precedence than `+`, so concatenation is done first, then comparison follows.

To make it produce your expected output, you need to override this operator precedence, just as you did in your second `sysout`, which will concatenate the result of the comparison to the string.

Answer (score 1):

So Java or any language has operator precedence, meaning some operations happen before others. In the first line, the "==" has a lower precedence (happens later) than "+", which happens earlier, so the output is the result of the "==" operation, which is *false*

see more on operator precedence here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Answer (score 0):

s5 == s3 checks if references are same are not.

s3 in created is string pool and s5 is new object and not referring to s3.